# How do I find the PHP equivalent of the MySQL WEEK function with mode 7?

Tags: php, mysql, mode, week-number

Using PHP, how do I find the week number where:

- the First day of week is Monday,
- week 1 is the first week with a Monday in this year,
- and the range is from 1-53?

I'm trying to achieve the PHP equivalent of the MySQL code:

```
SELECT WEEK(date('Y-m-d'), 7);
```

as seen on this website: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Example (What I'm trying to achieve in the wrong language, MySQL):

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT WEEK('2012-12-30', 7) as week");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "2012-12-30 = ".$result['week']."<br />";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT WEEK('2012-12-31', 7) as week");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "2012-12-31 = ".$result['week']."<br />";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT WEEK('2013-01-01', 7) as week");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "2013-01-01 = ".$result['week']."<br />";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT WEEK('2013-01-06', 7) as week");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "2013-01-06 = ".$result['week']."<br />";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT WEEK('2013-01-07', 7) as week");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "2013-01-07 = ".$result['week']."<br />";
```

Output: (The output I'm looking for)

```
2012-12-30 = 52
2012-12-31 = 53
2013-01-01 = 53
2013-01-06 = 53
2013-01-017 = 1
```

My Attempt: (In the correct language, PHP, but with the wrong result)

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-12-30');
echo "2012-12-30 = ".$date->format('W')."<br />";
$date = new DateTime('2012-12-31');
echo "2012-12-31 = ".$date->format('W')."<br />";
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-01');
echo "2013-01-01 = ".$date->format('W')."<br />";
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-06');
echo "2013-01-06 = ".$date->format('W')."<br />";
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-07');
echo "2013-01-07 = ".$date->format('W')."<br />";
```

Output (Wrong results)

```
2012-12-30 = 52
2012-12-31 = 01
2013-01-01 = 01
2013-01-06 = 01
2013-01-07 = 02
```

I feel like I'm missing something fairly fundamental. Any help on this would be very much appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Based on ISO standards PHP is correct. More Information on [ISO Week Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

Answer (score 0):

[`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) should help you. In your case this piece of code should do what you want:

`strftime(%V, strtotime('2013-01-21'))`

Comment: `%V` is the ISO definition of week, which is not what the asker is looking for. There are `%U` and `%W` that might produce the expected week.

Comment: I've tried to echo strftime("%V", strtotime('2013-01-01')); but for some reason, I get nothing. I then tried both echo strftime("%W", strtotime('2013-01-01')) and echo strftime("%U", strtotime('2013-01-01')) but both give 0 but I was trying to get 1. I have since managed to get the requirements changed and they are accepting the ISO standard, which means that there is no longer a need, but the questions is still interesting.